# How do I count a specific sequence in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, state-machine

I need to design a circuit that can count `1011` in a sequence of bits. For example, if the sequence is as shown in the picture, the count should be `1`, but it isn't. I know I'm reading input `w` not in a sequence way, but I don't know how to do it either.

> `w` is our input sequence and `CS` and `NS` are current state and
> next state. and parameters are our states. second picture's second state machine is what I used there is a slight difference between those two SMs.

[image: picture of circuit]

[image: picture of state machines. second one is what I used]

**main logic:**

```
module serialCounter(w,clk,resetn,z);
input w,clk,resetn;
output reg z;
reg [2:0] CS,NS;
reg [7:0] count;
parameter S0=3'b000, S1=3'b001, S2=3'b010, S3=3'b011, S4=3'b100;
always @(w,CS)
  case(CS)
    S0:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S1;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S1:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S2;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S2:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S2;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S3;
    end
    S3:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S4; 
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S4:begin NS=S0;end
endcase

always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn)
begin
  if(resetn == 0)
    CS<=S0;
  else
    CS<=NS;
end
always @(CS) 
begin
  if(CS==S4)
    begin 
      z=1;
      count<=count+1;
    end
end
endmodule
```

**testbench:**

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module counterTB();
reg w,clk,resetn;
reg [2:0] CS,NS;
wire z;
wire [7:0] count;
integer i;
serialCounter sk(.w(w),.clk(clk),.resetn(resetn),.z(z));
initial
  begin
    resetn = 1'b0;
    clk = 1'b0;
    CS=3'b000;
  end
initial
begin
  for(i=0;i<255;i=i+1)
    @(posedge clk, negedge resetn)  w=i;
end
always #5 clk = ~clk;


always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn) $monitor("w=%b, z=%b, count=%d", w,z,count);

endmodule
```

Comment: You should use variable names that mean something. It is very difficult for someone else to read and understand your code.

Comment: sorry @Moberg now I edited my question so you can understand my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is an easier way to created this state machine. The following example `reg [3:0]` pattern register which keeps 4 bits of the pattern. Then it just compares the pattern with the desired one (seq in this case).

```
module serialCounter(w, clk, resetn, z, counter);
    input w, clk, resetn;
    output reg z;
    output reg[7:0] counter;
  
  reg[3:0] pattern, tmp;
  parameter seq = 4'b1011;
  
  always@(posedge clk) begin
    if (!resetn) begin
      pattern <= 0;
      counter <= 0;
    end
    else begin
      tmp = (pattern << 1) | w;
      
      if (tmp == seq) begin
        counter <= counter + 1;
        z <= 1;
      end
      else
        z <= 0;
      
      pattern <= tmp;
    end
  end   
endmodule
  
module counterTB();
   reg w,clk,resetn;
   reg [2:0] CS,NS;
   wire z;
   reg [7:0] count;

  integer i;
  serialCounter sk(.w(w), .clk(clk), .resetn(resetn), .z(z), .counter(count));

initial
  begin
    resetn = 1'b0;
    clk = 1'b0;
    CS=3'b000;
    #30 resetn=1;
    #5000 $finish;
  end

always #5 clk = ~clk;

  initial $monitor("clk=%b, w=%b, z=%b, count=%d pattern=%b", clk, w,z, count, sk.pattern);

initial begin
  w = 0;
  forever #10 w = $random;
end
  
endmodule
```

I also fixed a couple of things in the tb module, e.g. $monitor should be used int an initial block. I changed the way you generate `w` as well.

Comment: I suggest to delete `CS`,`NS` and `i` since they don't do anything when I see waveform. and I have a question the pattern is correct but when I see the testbench, `w` is not equal to the pattern. Is it because of the clock? I mean we don't consider `w` when clock is `0`

Comment: `w` is a one bit random sequence of 1 and 0. It changes every clock cycle. isn't it what you expected? I used the testbench from the toolic's answer.  And yes, you should remove all unused vars.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

You asserted reset, but you never released it (`resetn` remains at 0).  You need to set it to 1 after a few clock cycles.

You need to drive your input `w` differently in the testbench.  Your design always samples it when it is 0.  One quick way is to drive it randomly.

You incorrectly modeled the `z` output, which I assume is your "detect" signal.  I also removed the `count` logic from that `always` block since it didn't seem to be doing anything important.

Here is code which now runs and detects the `1011` pattern on `w`:

```
module serialCounter(w,clk,resetn,z);
input w,clk,resetn;
output reg z;
reg [2:0] CS,NS;
reg [7:0] count;
parameter S0=3'b000, S1=3'b001, S2=3'b010, S3=3'b011, S4=3'b100;
always @(w,CS)
  case(CS)
    S0:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S1;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S1:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S2;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S2:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S2;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S3;
    end
    S3:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S4; 
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S4:begin NS=S0;end
endcase

always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn)
begin
  if(resetn == 0)
    CS<=S0;
  else
    CS<=NS;
end

always @* begin
  if(CS==S4) begin 
        z=1;
  end else begin
        z=0;
  end
end

endmodule



module counterTB();
reg w,clk,resetn;
reg [2:0] CS,NS;
wire z;
wire [7:0] count;
integer i;
serialCounter sk(.w(w),.clk(clk),.resetn(resetn),.z(z));

initial
  begin
    resetn = 1'b0;
    clk = 1'b0;
    CS=3'b000;
    #30 resetn=1;
    #5000 $finish;
  end

always #5 clk = ~clk;

always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn) $monitor("w=%b, z=%b, count=%d", w,z,count);

always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn) begin
    w <= $random;
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

There were some fixes to the code, first, we should get rid of inferred latches in the main logic (z and count), ended like this:

```
module serialCounter(w,clk,resetn,z);
input w,clk,resetn;
output reg z;
reg [2:0] CS,NS;
reg [7:0] count;
parameter S0=3'b000, S1=3'b001, S2=3'b010, S3=3'b011, S4=3'b100;
always @(w,CS)
  case(CS)
    S0:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S1;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S1:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S2;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S2:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S2;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S3;
    end
    S3:if(w==1)
    begin
      NS=S4;
    end
       else
    begin
      NS=S0;
    end
    S4:begin NS=S0;end
    default: NS=S0;
endcase

always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn)
begin
  if(resetn == 0)
    CS<=S0;
  else
    CS<=NS;
end
always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn)
begin
  if(resetn == 0)
    begin
      z<=0;
      count<=0;
    end
  if(CS==S4)
    begin
      z<=1;
      count<=count+1;
    end
end
endmodule
```

Secondly, in the test bench module, resetn was never changing from 0 to 1, as we have an asynchronous active-low reset, it was always in reset state, also, if you drive "w" with the least significant bit of the counter, it will be toggled every cycle. I changed it to a shifted register with a bit counter. The test bench worked like this:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module counterTB();
localparam WIDTH = 8;
reg clk,resetn;
reg [2:0] CS,NS;
wire w;
wire z;
wire [WIDTH-1:0] count;
reg  [WIDTH-1:0] w_reg;
reg  [WIDTH-1:0] w_nxt;
reg  [$clog2(WIDTH)-1:0] bit_count;
integer i;
serialCounter sk(.w(w),.clk(clk),.resetn(resetn),.z(z));
initial
  begin
    resetn = 1'b0;
    clk = 1'b0;
    CS=3'b000;
    w_reg = 0;
    w_nxt = 0;
  end

//DISABLE RESET
always #10 resetn = 1'b1;

always @ (posedge clk, negedge resetn) begin
  if(resetn == 0) begin
    w_reg <= 0;
    w_nxt <= 1;
    bit_count <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    if(bit_count == (WIDTH-1)) begin
      if(&w_nxt) begin
        $finish;
      end
      else begin
        w_reg <= w_nxt;
        w_nxt <= w_nxt + 1;
        bit_count <= 0;
      end
    end
    else begin
      w_reg <= w_reg >> 1;
      bit_count <= bit_count + 1;
    end
  end
end

assign w = w_reg[0];

always #5 clk = ~clk;

always @(posedge clk, negedge resetn) $monitor("w=%b, z=%b, count=%d, w_reg=%x, w_nxt=%h, bit_count=%d, reset=%b", w,z,sk.count,w_reg,w_nxt,bit_count,resetn);

endmodule
```

The last part of the output of the simulation (it counts up to 255):

```
w=0, z=1, count=104, w_reg=fa, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=0, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=104, w_reg=7d, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=1, reset=1
w=0, z=1, count=104, w_reg=3e, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=2, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=1f, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=3, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=0f, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=4, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=07, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=5, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=03, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=6, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=01, w_nxt=fb, bit_count=7, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=fb, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=0, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=7d, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=1, reset=1
w=0, z=1, count=105, w_reg=3e, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=2, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=1f, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=3, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=105, w_reg=0f, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=4, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=07, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=5, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=03, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=6, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=01, w_nxt=fc, bit_count=7, reset=1
w=0, z=1, count=106, w_reg=fc, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=0, reset=1
w=0, z=1, count=106, w_reg=7e, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=1, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=3f, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=2, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=1f, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=3, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=0f, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=4, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=07, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=5, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=03, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=6, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=01, w_nxt=fd, bit_count=7, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=fd, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=0, reset=1
w=0, z=1, count=106, w_reg=7e, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=1, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=3f, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=2, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=106, w_reg=1f, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=3, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=107, w_reg=0f, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=4, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=107, w_reg=07, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=5, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=107, w_reg=03, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=6, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=107, w_reg=01, w_nxt=fe, bit_count=7, reset=1
w=0, z=1, count=107, w_reg=fe, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=0, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=107, w_reg=7f, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=1, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=107, w_reg=3f, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=2, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=108, w_reg=1f, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=3, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=108, w_reg=0f, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=4, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=108, w_reg=07, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=5, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=108, w_reg=03, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=6, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=108, w_reg=01, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=7, reset=1
w=1, z=1, count=108, w_reg=01, w_nxt=ff, bit_count=7, reset=1
```